# Data overlay filter

Tags: views, javascript

I have an OpenLayers View created to display products at various locations. I have some locations that don't have any products yet; therefore, should NOT be displayed. My page view filters these out perfectly but the Map still displays the locations without products.

My assumption is that the points that are drawn on to the map are generated by the OpenLayers Data Overlay. I've tried multiple filters but none seem to affect the View. Even changing the Content Type doesn't change the output of the OpenLayers Data Overlay.

Any idea on how I can get the Map to ONLY display those results given in the page view?

Answer (score 0):

If you make sure to use the filters across all view elements, this should work.

It's the data overlay views that are producing the output for the page view to overlay. You can see this data in the preview panel on views.

You may even consider putting your filters on the data overlay view only and not the page view.